# Solution to the Klein-Gordon equation in a generic metric

Tags: field-theory, differential-equations, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Is there a way to solve the Klein-Gordon equation in a generic spacetime for a massless scalar field?
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\phi)=0.
\end{equation}
In Minkowski spacetime, using the $(t,x,y,z)$ coordinates, what is usually done is to perform a Fourier transform of the field and then write the Fourier modes using tempered distributions.
Is there a similar method to solve the general equation above?

Comment: In Minkowski space you can expand via plane waves $\sim\exp(ip\cdot x)$, in general case you should find exact modes. In case of AdS spacetime, you can (for instance) check  https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2557 (section III, subsection A). Also, check book by Birrell & Davies "QFT in Curved Space"

Comment: *Is there a way to solve the Klein-Gordon equation in a generic spacetime for a massless scalar field?* No. Nor the Dirac equation. Nor the Maxwell equations.